# Android, how do I release a file lock from a file that I have deleted

Tags: android, mono, directory, locking

I need to delete and recreate a directory in my Android (written with Mono) app when the user wants to change log in details. I delete the directory thus:

```
 Directory.Delete(AppDataFolder, true);
```

However, when I try to recreate the directory, using:

```
 Directory.CreateDirectory(aDirectory);
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Lock violation on path /storage/sdcard0/Telecetera/Connect For                                  Android
```

I can't see how to fix this. Has anyone got any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, did you figure this one out?